# Simulation of suicide burn in openai-gym's LunarLander

Tags: python, simulation, game-physics, physics, openai-gym

I want to simulate [suicide burn](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10307/what-is-a-suicide-burn) to learn and understand rocket landing. OpenAI gym already has an LunarLander enviroment which is used for training reinforcement learning agents. I am using this enviroment to simulate suicide burn in python. I have extracted the coordinates `(x,y)` from the first two values of state vector of this enviroment. From these values, considering `y` coordinates as the altitude; I have calculated velocity and accelartion of the falling lander using these equations

```
velocity(v) = delta_y/ delta_t
acceleartion(a) = delta_v/delta_t
```

As the simulation is incrementing stepwise the difference in time `delta_t` was taken as 1. Unable to find the gravity parameter of LunarLander I gave it a default value `g=1`. Then using the below equation from this [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalAcademy/comments/4c42rz/maths_help_calculating_when_to_suicide_burn/d1fgqkf/)

> altitude to start suicide burn = [ (current altitude)(acceleration of gravity) + (1/2)(current velocity)2 ] / (acceleration of engines)

I tried to calculate altitude to start suicide burn. This is my full python code. I am only planning to use two actions 0(do nothing) and 2(start main engine) of the four possible actions.

```
import gym
env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
env.seed(0)

g = 1
delta_t = 1
action = 0

state = env.reset()

# x0 = state[0]
y0 = state[1]
v0 = 0

for t in range(3000):
    state, reward, done, _  = env.step(action)
    y = state[1]
    if done or y <0:
        break
    v = (y-y0)/delta_t  # velocity
    a = (v - v0)/delta_t # acceleration

    # (altitude to start suicide burn) = [ (current altitude)(acceleration of gravity) + (1/2)(current velocity)2 ] / (acceleration of engines)
    alt_burn = [y*g+0.5*v*v]/a

    v0 = v
    y0 = y

    print(" y",round(y,5)," v",round(v,5)," a",round(a,5)," Alt_burn",round(alt_burn[0],5))
```

The output results looks something like this

```
 y 1.41542  v 0.00196  a 0.00196  Alt_burn 722.35767
 y 1.41678  v 0.00136  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2362.78166
 y 1.41754  v 0.00076  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2362.63867
 y 1.4177  v 0.00016  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2362.43506
 y 1.41726  v -0.00044  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2362.64046
 y 1.41622  v -0.00104  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2359.03148
 y 1.41458  v -0.00164  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2358.17355
 y 1.41233  v -0.00224  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2353.50518
 y 1.40949  v -0.00284  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2349.24118
 y 1.40605  v -0.00344  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2343.51016
 y 1.40201  v -0.00404  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2336.31535
 y 1.39737  v -0.00464  a -0.0006  Alt_burn -2329.04954
```

If we look at altitude(y) its a very small value less than 1.5 whereas the calculated altitude to start suicide burn are very high. How can I solve this problem?

In the reddit comments they have only mentioned to start the engine but not to end it. Anyone knows the math for killing the engine dynamically?

Comment: Is the `for t in range(3000)` loop supposed to be going through times `0` through `3000`? Also, is there any atmosphere present?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, `Is the for t in range(3000) loop supposed to be going through times 0 through 3000?` 3000 is just a very big number. I just needed a very large number. `Also, is there any atmosphere present?` I really don't know there is not much details available in this environments docs.

Comment: I get that you need a large number, but what is it (`t`) representing physically? Is it the physical time of the simulation?

Comment: Not the physical time, I cant represent time so I used the idea of time step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `delta_t` should be `1.0/50.0` according to the [`lunar_lander` source](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander.py#L281)

> ```
>  FPS = 50
>  #...
>  self.world.Step(1.0/FPS, 6*30, 2*30)
> ```

with the [`Box2D` documentation](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/wiki/manual#simulating-the-world-of-box2d) indicating the typical time step by

> ```
>  # [...]Typically we use a time step of 1/60 of a
>  # second (60Hz) and 6 velocity/2 position iterations. This provides a 
>  # high quality simulation in most game scenarios.
>  timeStep = 1.0 / 60
> ```

2. The acceleration of the engines should not be defined as the current acceleration as it is in

```
alt_burn = [y*g+0.5*v*v]/a
```

but by the impulse of the engines, defined [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander.py#L38) as

> ```
> MAIN_ENGINE_POWER  = 13.0
> ```

The mass of the lander is not specified in the [creation of the lander body](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander.py#L161), but using

```py
env.lander.mass
```

we can find the mass to be `4.82`. Given this, the correct acceleration for the engines is given by<sup>1</sup>

```py
alt_burn = (y * g + 0.5 * v*v) / (13.0 / env.lander.mass * 0.5)
```

If we run the code with the above modifications,

```py
import gym
env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
env.seed(0)

g = 1.0
delta_t = 1.0/50.0
action = 0

state = env.reset()

y0 = state[1]

for t in range(3000):
    state, reward, done, _  = env.step(action)
    y = state[1]
    v = (y - y0) / delta_t
    y0 = y
    if done or y < 0:
        break

    alt_burn = (y*g+0.5*v*v)/(13.0 / env.lander.mass * 0.5)

    print(" y",round(y,5)," v",round(v,5)," Alt_burn",round(alt_burn,5))
```

we get a much more reasonable answer for the burn altitude:

```
 y 1.41542  v 0.09797  Alt_burn 1.05242
 y 1.41678  v 0.06799  Alt_burn 1.05158
 y 1.41754  v 0.03799  Alt_burn 1.05097
 y 1.4177  v 0.00799  Alt_burn 1.05057
 y 1.41726  v -0.02201  Alt_burn 1.0504
 y 1.41622  v -0.05202  Alt_burn 1.05045
 y 1.41458  v -0.08202  Alt_burn 1.05073
 y 1.41233  v -0.11202  Alt_burn 1.05123
 y 1.40949  v -0.14202  Alt_burn 1.05194
 y 1.40605  v -0.17202  Alt_burn 1.05289
 y 1.40201  v -0.20202  Alt_burn 1.05405
 y 1.39737  v -0.23202  Alt_burn 1.05544
 y 1.39213  v -0.26203  Alt_burn 1.05705
 y 1.38629  v -0.29202  Alt_burn 1.05887
 ...
 y 0.56683  v -1.58312  Alt_burn 1.34863
 y 0.53456  v -1.61311  Alt_burn 1.36025
 y 0.5017  v -1.64311  Alt_burn 1.37209
 y 0.46824  v -1.67311  Alt_burn 1.38416
 y 0.43418  v -1.70311  Alt_burn 1.39644
 y 0.39951  v -1.73311  Alt_burn 1.40895
 y 0.36425  v -1.76311  Alt_burn 1.42168
 y 0.32839  v -1.79311  Alt_burn 1.43463
 y 0.29193  v -1.82311  Alt_burn 1.44781
 y 0.25487  v -1.85311  Alt_burn 1.46121
 y 0.2172  v -1.88311  Alt_burn 1.47483
 y 0.17894  v -1.91311  Alt_burn 1.48867
 y 0.14008  v -1.94311  Alt_burn 1.50274
 y 0.10062  v -1.97311  Alt_burn 1.51702
 y 0.06055  v -2.00311  Alt_burn 1.53154
 y 0.01989  v -2.03311  Alt_burn 1.54626
```

The execution of the suicide burn<sup>2</sup> is now trivial, we simply need to activate the engines when the lander is below burn altitude and deactivate them when the lander is below a cutoff altitude.

```py
import gym
env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
env.seed(0)

g = 1.0
delta_t = 1.0/50.0
action = 0

state = env.reset()

y0 = state[1]
v0 = 0
cut_off = 0.01

for t in range(3000):
    env.render()
    state, reward, done, _  = env.step(action)
    y = state[1]
    v = (y - y0)/delta_t
    if done or y < 0 or v == 0.001:
        break

    alt_burn = (y*g+0.5*v*v)/(13.0 / env.lander.mass * 0.5)

    v0 = v
    y0 = y
    if y < alt_burn and y > cut_off:
        action = 2
    else:
        action = 0

    print(" y",round(y,5)," v",round(v,5)," Alt_burn",round(alt_burn,5))
```

And the lander will hoverslam:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup>Shamefully I can't find a source for this equation. I have a degree in Applied Physics with an emphasis in Astrophysics and over 1000 hours of [KSP](https://www.kerbalspaceprogram.com/) - so I am absolutely certain this equation is correct, but I cannot for the life of me remember where I got it from.

<sup>2</sup>This brand of suicide burn is also referred to as a *hoverslam*. SpaceX coined this term because when landing a Falcon 9 Booster, one engine at minimum thrust generates a TWR greater than 1.00, meaning there is no capacity for a [Powered Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_program#Lunar_mission_profile) like that used by the Apollo Missions. Consequently, there is only an instantaneous hover - hence *hoverslam*.